# I want to install ubuntu 12.04 in my netbook is i right is it applicable i also want to ask what version should i download 32 or 64

Tags: 12.04, installation

Intel Atom CPU N570 @ 1.66ghz
2.00 GB RAM 
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit Sp1
Clevo m1110m

i decided to install the ubuntu 12.04.03 rather than windows 7 because they say that ubuntu is mush faster than windows 7....but i have the question it it applicable to install it in my netbook.   PLEASE ANSWER AS SOON AS POSIBLE THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

That [CPU is 64-bit](http://ark.intel.com/products/55637/), so you'll want to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

2GB of RAM isn't a lot, but it'll be plenty to run Ubuntu. If you find that the UI is slow, disable the 3D desktop effects.

I haven't used that specific laptop, but Ubuntu works pretty much flawlessly on nearly all modern hardware. Give it a go and I'm sure you'll be happy with the results.

Comment: Thank You very much mister ..uhhmm but i dont know how to install it in my netbook....i dont want to use any disc or usb what should i do..please help......i have an iso file of ubuntu 12.04 32 bit but i dont know how to install........once again thank you very much..please answer my question as soon as posible ..thank you

Comment: To install Ubuntu, you need to use a CD, DVD, or USB stick. Search Google, and you'll find lots of tutorials.

Comment: yes..but is there a way to install ubuntu without cd,dvd or any usb ....please help me i dont want to use anything i just want to use my computer......is there a way thank you......please answer me as soon as posible

Comment: @MarukoAntero, I already answered that question: a CD, DVD, or USB stick must be used to install Ubuntu.

Comment: mister i already use pendrive and creat bootable disc i restarted my computer but it did not boot?????what should i do